# Is there a way to remove transition effect on a particular element within transition element?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm applying transition for background image.Now I placed text within the same div.But I don't want transition effect for this text,I'm applying fade in  effect for it.

Html

```
<div class="small-12 medium-12 large-12  columns home cover">

    <div id="target">
        <div class="small-12 medium-11 large-11 columns text2">
                 Beyond Law,<br/>
                 The Spirit of Innovation is Our strenght.
                 </div>
    </div>


</div>

<div style="clear: both"></div>
```

script

```
<script>

  $(document).ready(function () {

        $('#target').toggleClass("wide");

});

  </script>
```

css

```
.cover
{width: 100%; z-index:2000; position: relative; overflow: hidden;margin-bottom: 5%;}
#target {
    position: relative;
    left:0;

    background-image:url('../img/top-bg.jpg');background-repeat:no-repeat;
     width: 120%;
    transition: all 2s ease-in-out;
    background-size:cover;
     height: 600px;
}


/*#target:hover {
    left: -20%;
}*/

#target.wide{
    left: -20%;
    padding-left: 30%;
}
.text2
{
    margin-top:10%;
    margin-left:0;
    padding-left:0;


    /*fade in effect*/
    transition-delay: 2s;
        animation: fadein 2s;
    -moz-animation: fadein 2s; /* Firefox */
    -webkit-animation: fadein 2s; /* Safari and Chrome */
    -o-animation: fadein 2s; /* Opera */

}

@keyframes fadein {
    from {
        opacity:0;
    }
    to {
        opacity:1;
    }
}
@-moz-keyframes fadein { /* Firefox */
    from {
        opacity:0;
    }
    to {
        opacity:1;
    }
}
@-webkit-keyframes fadein { /* Safari and Chrome */
    from {
        opacity:0;
    }
    to {
        opacity:1;
    }
}
@-o-keyframes fadein { /* Opera */
    from {
        opacity:0;
    }
    to {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}
```

**can refer the link here: http://vani.valse.com.my/beldon/index.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're animating the `left` and `padding-left` properties, which by their very nature will effect all the child elements. To achieve the same effect, you could animate the `background-position` property.

Something along the lines of:

```
#target {
  background-position: 200px 50%;
  transition: background-position 2s ease-in-out;
}

#target.wide {
  background-position: 0px 50%;
}
```

Comment: oh, what about just `background-position`?

Comment: then it moves little from top to bottom in firefox..But i want it to move right to left like in chrome.

Comment: i added -moz-transition:all .2s ease-in-out;...it's works somehow but not smooth transition.

Comment: I don't have firefox on my computer, so you might have to work with me a little. I think you need to set the y position at 50%, since it looks like you want the center of the image.

Comment: background-y:50%; doesn't change anything.WIth  -moz-transition:all .2s ease-in-out it works but no smooth transition only in mozilla

Comment: because, like you said, FF does not support background-position-x/y

Answer (score 0):

Remove the transition from all elements within it.

```
#target * { transition: none}
```

Comment: I don't get you.U mean I should remove for #target?

Comment: No as i said this will remove it for all elements within target but not for target